# Trying to remove specific items from an already populated Combobox VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

In VBA I am writing a code that gathers information based off an initial input in a userform.

From the initial entrance point I want the code to go out and find the corresponding data and add it. I have that all working well.

But I am gathering the data from a pivot table and if the **pivot table is open it returns "" spaces, "(blank)" and "Grand Total", which I want to get rid of**.

My Current code is:

```
lcomboCount = Sheets(pt).PivotTables("Pivottable1").TableRange2.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lcomboCount
datapoint = Sheets(pt).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("combo").LabelRange.Offset(i, 0).Value
UserForm1.ComboBox.AddItem Sheets(pt).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("combo").LabelRange.Offset(i, 0)
Next i
For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox.ListCount - 1
If Me.ComboBox = "" Or Me.ComboBox = "Grand Total" Or Me.ComboBox = ("(blank)") Then
    Me.ComboBox.RemoveItem (i)
End If
Next i
```

I had a `Msgbox` in there at one point to see if my values were reading correctly and they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `.List(i)` when you test the values stored into the ComboBox.

Also I changed the "direction" *(see second comment for details)* of the second loop to avoid missing items.

Here is you revised code :

```
lcomboCount = Sheets(pt).PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lcomboCount
    datapoint = Sheets(pt).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("combo").LabelRange.Offset(i, 0).Value
    UserForm1.ComboBox.AddItem datapoint
Next i
For i = Me.ComboBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.ComboBox.List(i) = "" Or Me.ComboBox.List(i) = "Grand Total" Or Me.ComboBox.List(i) = ("(blank)") Then
        Me.ComboBox.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Serious question, can you explain why the "direction" of the loop could have missed things the way it was. For my own knowledge please.

Comment: If you go from `0 to Something.Count`, and delete items, you'll have an "out of range" error because there'll be lesser and lesser items during your loop. In the opposite direction, you'll go from `Something.Count to 0` and avoid that kind of issue! ;)
(same problems with sheets, workbooks, charts, shapes, ...)

Comment: Makes perfect sense once you said it.  Thank you.

Comment: I received the compiling error: Method or data member not found for .item :(. I am using ms 2010 if that changes anything

Comment: My bad, I think it is `.List` for Comboboxes and not `.Item`, give it a try

Comment: Glad I could help! ;)
So just 2 quick pointers for that site : once your problem is solved, you can accept an answer (tick right under up/down votes, that'll become green) to mark your question as answered. And use the up/down votes when you find something useful or not (question or answer)